# Oracle SQL Grouping/Ordering

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm looking for some help in writing an Oracle SQL statement to accomplish the following ...

Let's say I have the following data:

```
YEAR | PLACE
1984 | somewhere
1983 | work
1985 | somewhere
1982 | home
1984 | work
1983 | home
1984 | somewhere
```

How can I get a result that keeps all the PLACE column values together and orders it by the YEAR column ... so the result I'm looking for is:

```
YEAR | PLACE
1982 | home
1983 | home
1983 | work
1984 | work
1984 | somewhere
1984 | somewhere
1985 | somewhere
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Just to illustrate answers to some of the questions asked ... let's say I add the following data to my original data:

```
1981 | somewhere
```

Now the result should be:

```
YEAR | PLACE
1981 | somewhere
1984 | somewhere
1984 | somewhere
1985 | somewhere
1982 | home
1983 | home
1983 | work
1984 | work
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do the "work" rows sort between "home" and "somewhere"?  That implies that you want `place` sorted something other than alphabetically-- what is that method?

Comment: What if you have also `1982 | somewhere`?

Comment: It seems like he just wants to order the years and group the place.

Comment: select year, place from my_table group by place order by year;

Comment: Alan, I believe that would work on most SQL servers, but on the Oracle server I'm dealing with I get the following error: 'not a GROUP BY expression' ... I believe Oracle only allows GROUP BY usage in certain scenarios ... hence my problem :)

Comment: To answer Hamlet's question ... if I had '1982 | somewhere' then that would put all the somewhere values either before all the home values (since home also has 1982 as its lowest year) or just after the home values.  If I had '1981 | somewhere' then that would place all the somewhere values at the top of the results.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/681855?start=0&tstart=0 it's the same problem, but I don't know if it'll help ya!

Comment: @HarryMuscle and you are wrong, that query would not work anywhere properly, because it's invalid SQL syntax. And you don't need `GROUP BY` at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a window aggregate function:

```
SELECT 
    year, 
    place
FROM 
    tablename
ORDER BY
    MIN(year) OVER (PARTITION BY place),
    place,
    year ;
```

Tested at: **[SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2561/2)**

Comment: @GriffeyDog, thnx. You already have my upvote, I was just lucky to see this question just after the OP clarified.

Answer (score 1):

REVISED base on the OPs comments:

```
select a.year, a.place
from my_table a join
  (select place, min(year) as min_year from my_table group by place) b on a.place = b.place
order by b.min_year, a.place, a.year
```

Comment: Unfortunately the PLACE column has hundreds of possible values.

Comment: Well, do you care what the actual order of `place` is, or just that they are grouped together?

Comment: They need to be grouped together and ordered by the YEAR column ... so yes the order matters.

Comment: The edited answer still won't work cause that groups all the places together alphabetically and then orders the years within the identical places ... I need the places to be ordered based on the YEAR column ... not based on the alphabet.